# d3 tree that loads more node on click plus other things

Tags: javascript, d3.js, tree

How can I make a d3 tree layout with the following features:
1. clicking a node ajax-loads more child nodes of clicked node
2. first children layer will be laid out normally in 1 line, but next children level need to appear all around their parent.
3. I need the page to expand vertically (show scroll) if needed, when new nodes appear

Is it possible or I better develop it on my own?

Comment: 1 and 3 are certainly possible, it sounds like you would want to create your own layout for 2 though.

Comment: I ended up implementing my own code to have full control

Comment: Can we access the code online?